# How to wire a 2 stage heat pump with gas furnace

Tags: wiring, hvac, pump, nest, heat

I bought a new house last year and this is the first winter I've been in it. It have a gas furnace that we've been using as the only heat source. The other day, I went to clean the condensor coils and realized the outdoor unit is a 2 stage heat pump (there's 2 separate compressors), but for some reason it's not wired to utilize the heat pump for heat, nor is it wired to utilize the 2 stages for cooling.

Instead of having it like it currently is with 100% gas heat, I'd like to wire it to use the heat pump for heat and use gas as the backup or aux/e-heat. I'd also like to wire it to utilize both stages.

The unit is an American standard  Heritage 18 , model # 2a6h8048

The tstat wires are landed on the Y1, G, Rc, and W1 terminals.
The air handler terminal strip only has slots for
C,G,R,W, and Y wires.

I have a 3rd gen nest learning  tstat.

Can what I'm wanting to do be done? Thanks!

**tStat wiring:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv4Pc.jpg

**Air handler control board:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3KMo.jpg

**Control board wiring:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j8FF.jpg <---- The white wire on the C terminal and the red on the Y are the 2 wires going out to the heat pump. The other 4 wires go the stat.

**Outdoor heat pump wiring:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDoTU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sbl9.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfDdK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN9HD.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMIK1.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWixN.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajcCx.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0pcN.jpg

**Nameplate:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHkao.jpg

Not sure you can follow the individual wires in that rat's nest, but in one of the pics you can see the red and white wires that are coming from the indoor unit. The white wire is wire nutted to the blue wire which is connected to the heat pump board, and the red wire is nutted with a yellow, red, orange, and yellow/red stripe wire which are also connected to the board.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air-handler and the outdoor unit please?

Comment: There's some pics I took of the air handler yesterday. The white wire on the C terminal and the red on the Y are the 2 wires going out to the heat pump. I'll add some of the heat pump wiring later. I know I'll have to pull a cable with more wires which won't be a problem. I just don't know how many wires to get.

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate on the outdoor unit for that matter?

Comment: Nameplate pic added

Comment: Install manual for the outdoor unit: https://manualzz.com/doc/6334248/installer-s-guide (sorry, but it was the best I could find)

Comment: Thank you!  From page 5 of that manual,  the field wiring diagram on the air handler shows several terminals that mine doesn't have, y2, w2, w3, b, and o. Silly question,  but do I simply bypass the air handler board for those specific wires?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wants both a B and an O, that might be an issue since Nests can only provide one or the other...